# Is tree view available in Finder in Lion?

Tags: finder

I've seen on several forums that people use a tree view for their folders in Finder but I can't find anywhere how to switch to it.

Is the tree view available in OSX Lion?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The way *items* are shown in Finder can be configured through the folder's Toolbar, which gives four *default* options:

[image: Finder's displaying options]

- **Icon View** - Which is the regular layout of icons.
- **List View** - The items are shown in a list-like and can be navigated as a **tree**.

[image: The List View]

- **Columns View** - Items are displayed through columns which show the file's path.

[image: The Columns View]

- **CoverFlow** - Items are shown with the regular *coverflow* efect.

**Note:** While in a folder, you can switch through these options by doing <kbd>Command</kbd> + the option's number (**1** is the icon's view, **2** is the list view, etc).

Comment: **Important**: The list view only shows the tree if *Arrange* has no criteria selected